# Python3 wrong string encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, character-encoding

I've got an application where you can login via SAML2. I'm using apache mellon module and getting data:

```
name = request.environ['MELLON_name']
email = request.environ['MELLON_mail']
```

From those data I create JWT using [flask_jwt_simpe](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-simple) library. Then I want to call `get_jwt_identity()`, but the name in response has wrong encoding, it looks `JiÅÃ­ Manes` instead of `Jiří Manes` (Czech language). How can i solve this problem?

**Edit #1**: `locale` command output

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

**Edit #2:** Solved it on my VPS by following python code:

`name = bytearray(request.environ['MELLON_name'], 'iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')`

But I would like to have another universal solution :-/

Comment: The strings in `environ` are passed through environment variables by, presumably, Apache/Mellon. It's storing UTF-8, but apparently Python/Flask doesn't know that, so it assumes environment variables are in your default locale, which appears to be Latin-1. So, you need to read them as raw bytes (so you can explicitly `decode('utf-8')` them), or you need to configure Flask to override the default encoding, or you need to configure your system to `en_US.UTF-8` or something else appropriate. I'm not sure how you do the first two, but I'm sure it's in the Flask docs.

Comment: @abarnert I've edited my question, my system seems to be configured right :-(

Comment: Which Python version? If it's an old-enough 3.x, you may need a setlocale or something somewhere, but I'm not sure, and in 3.6+ that won't make a difference.

Comment: I've got version 3.5.2

Comment: I honestly don't know how Python reads env variables in 3.4 and 3.5. Any other version from 1.5 to 3.7… :) Anyway, I don't know what's going on except that someone somewhere on the path between the actual environment and your code is definitely decoding some UTF-8 as if it were Latin-1. Hopefully someone else will know why.

Comment: You might want to add the `flask` tag to attract the resident Flask experts (and make it clear exactly how your server is getting launched/dispatched, or whatever else seems relevant).

Comment: If you run `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, what is returned?

Comment: whats the value of request.environ['MELLON_name'] without any encoding? so that we can reproduce the issue and verify into [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ingerklekacz it returns `utf-8`

Comment: @Prateek how do I determine this?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the part where the user is authenticating via SAML. Is it possible that the SAML source encoding is set to 'iso-8859-1'? If that's the case, and you don't have control over the SAML IDP, the workaround you've found is probably the best solution you're going to find.

Comment: @user3216673 `print(request.environ['MELLON_name']` ?

Comment: @Prateek it prints out `Ji\xc3\x85\xc2\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xad Manes`

Comment: @user3216673 When `print(request.environ['MELLON_name'])` prints out raw bytes it must be a bytestring. Is it prefixed with a `b` like `b'Ji\xc3\x85\xc2\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xad Manes'`? In that case something is not right, you can't decode bytestrings: `bytearray(request.environ['MELLON_name'], 'iso-8859-1')` This should throw an exception.

Comment: `print(type(request.environ['MELLON_name']))` and `print(repr(request.environ['MELLON_name']))` would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit the [WSGI encoding dance](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/python3/).  Unfortunately, there isn't really a better solution than the one you've already found.

As you can see, you are already doing the [same](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0bc61df6e1ae9f2ffdf5d066aa3cd9d5ebcb307d/werkzeug/_compat.py#L175-L176) as werkzeug (which is the WSGI package used by Flask) to solve this issue.

If you wanted, you could use the compatibility functions in that package, but you may find they change without notification being in a private module, so you're probably best off sticking to your own equivalent code.